# find out which sampling points are in the same geographical rectangle and extract this information

Tags: r, grid, extract, sample, rectangles

this is my first time asking a question here. I hope I arrive to formulate it precise enough.

I'm a marine biologist working with biological data sampled at different sites in the North Sea and the English Channel. My data constitute of the longitude and latitude of every sampling site as well a name / number of each sampling site arranged in columns.

The sampling area is devided in statisticle rectangles according to the CRS grid measuring one degree longitude and 0.5 degree latitude. I want to know which sampling sites are in the same statisticle rectangle and to extract this information as additional column in my dataset.

I tried to use the code provided here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210092/plotting-square-grids-on-a-map-and-extracting-each-grid-information-using-r
and to adapt it to my purpose, but I do not succeed. Basically I am stucked to create a grid that represents the grid of the world map zoomed in to my study region and with the grid cell size described above as a SpatialGrid object.

Can someone help me with this or has a different idea how to approach my objective?

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of your dataset, it is not very easy to help you if we can't see what the data looks like

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! I will consider them for the next time asking a question. With regard to my question above I found an answer already.